# Can i exclude a word in my pattern?

Tags: .net, regex

I know i can do something like ab[^c]+def which should match ab_blah_hi_blah_def but is there a way to do something like

```
ab(^hi)+def
```

which will exclude the word hi causeing ab_blah_hi_blah_def to fail? but not ab_blah_h_i_blah_def

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead to do something like this. The pattern `(?!foobar).` matches every character, except the f in "foobar".

So to match every word but "hi", you could use `^((?!hi)\w)+$`.

Comment: perfect. I had a feeling this was possible after your last answer. Great, this will be very useful to me in the future :)

Comment: You can find this and many other useful tipps at http://www.regular-expressions.info/